# A consequence of simply connectedness

Tags: differential-topology

Is it true that if a manifold is simply connected then its tangent bundle is simply connected?

Answer (score 4):

The tangent bundle is homotopy equivalent to the manifold and therefore has the same fundamental group as the manifold. In particular, they are simply connected simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This follows from a portion of the long exact sequence of a fibration: the tangent bundle $TM$ of a $d$-dimensional manifold $M$ is a fibration with fiber $\mathbb{R}^d$ and so there is an exact sequence
$$\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^d) \to \pi_1(TM) \to \pi_1(M)
$$